# Laravel: Check if row exists single query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have comments on articles that can have reactions, which are anonymously given based on IP.

**reactions table:**

`id | comment_id | ip | type`

**App\Comment**:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function article() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }

    public function reactions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reaction')
                ->selectRaw('*, COUNT(type) as count')
                ->groupBy('type')
                ->orderBy('count', 'desc');
    }
}
```

**ArticleController@index:**

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::orderBy('views', 'desc')->get();

    return view('wiki')->withArticles($articles);
}
```

How do I fetch the reaction given by the user's current IP (if they have) in the single `Article::orderBy` query above? i.e.,

`Reaction::where(['comment_id' => $id, 'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']])->count();`

It could be checked within the loop for each comment, but that's obviously inefficient...

It should be available like so:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @if ($comment->given_reaction [or something])
            // ...
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$articles = Article::with(['comments' => function($q) use ($ip) {
    $q->with('reactions' => function($q) use ($ip) {
         $q->where('ip' => $ip)
    })
}])->orderBy('views', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: IIRC, it's safer to use Laravel/Symfony's `Request::ip()` (especially where the webserver may be behind a proxy of some kind, like a load balancer).